# Find $r$ when $r>15$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

A light-bulb flickers after every so often in minutes, and the time taken between each flicker is recorded. In total 5 observations are counted, and the time between each has been recorded as the following:

$$x_1=2.5, x_2=5.4, x_3 = 6.4, x_4 = 2.1$$

However, the 5th observation is only recorded when the time between flickers is greater than 15 minutes, so we have $x_5 > 15$.

Calculate the sample mean.

Here's what I have tried:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^5x_i = \frac{2.5+5.3+6.4+2.1+r}{5}=3.26+\frac{r}{5}$$

Where $r$ represents $x_5 > 15$. However, how do I find a value for $r$ if possible? The original question asks for this distribution to find the MLE of $X \sim \exp(\lambda;x)$. Give the MLE of $\exp(\lambda;x)$ is $\bar{x}$, I thought the interpretation I gave would be the answer. Please let me know if an alternative approach was required!

Comment: I don't understand.  The time between flickers is what it is.  If we observe $g$ for the fifth gap, are you suggesting that we put down $\min(15,g)$?   That doesn't see sensible but I can't think of anything else.  And of course we have no idea what the distribution of $g$ is.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  As it stands I have no idea how the data point $r_5$ is defined and of course the question can not be answered without that.

Comment: @lulu essentially the time between each flicker can be modelled with an exponential distribution $\lambda$, and to estimate $\lambda$ each flicker is timed. The light switch is being tested for mechanistic faults, a faster flickering light is likely to be new whereas one that flicks slowly has been used more. I'm meant to calculate this using log MLE however the MLE of an exponential distribution is $\lambda = \frac{1}{\bar{x}}$ and so I calculated the sample mean assuming $L(\theta;x) = \prod_{i=1}^5\lambda^5e^{\lambda x} \implies \log L(\theta;x) = 5\log(\lambda)-\lambda \sum_{i=1}^5 x_i$

Comment: @lulu because we do not know the actual time of $r$, I thought to try an estimate it using the MLE. Unless I'm supposed to approach the method differently?

Comment: Sorry, not following.  I don't understand why the statement is so cryptic regarding the fifth data point.  From the look of the first four data points, I'd have guessed the most likely data point above $15$ was $15.1$ (as it appears you are measuring in increments of one tenth of a second).  But using four data points is a terrible way to model complicated data.

Comment: It seems to me that the average value of the last observation is equal to $15 + A$. This leads to: $A = (2.5 + 5.3 + 6.4 + 2.1 + 15 + A)/5$. Solve this and you get $A = 31.3/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_5$ are i.i.d Exponential random variables with mean $1/\lambda$. Let $f$ be their common density function. Regarding your original question on MLE of $\lambda$, I think what you have is an instance of Type-I (right) [censoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)). There are $4$ uncensored observations and the $5$th observation is [right-censored](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144037/119261).

So for $x_i>0$ and $\lambda>0$, the likelihood here takes the form

\begin{align}
L(\lambda \mid \boldsymbol x)&=\prod_{i=1}^4f(x_i)\cdot P(X_5>15)
\\&=\prod_{i=1}^4 (\lambda e^{-\lambda x_i})\cdot e^{-15\lambda}
\\&=\lambda^4 \exp\left\{-\lambda\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i-15\lambda\right\} \tag{1}
\end{align}

One can also say that the data is $(Y_i,\delta_i)$ where $Y_i=\min(X_i,15)$ and $\delta_i=I(X_i\le 15)$, for which the likelihood is

$$L(\lambda\mid \boldsymbol y,\boldsymbol\delta)=\prod_{i=1}^5 (\lambda e^{-\lambda y_i})^{\delta_i}(e^{-15\lambda})^{1-\delta_i} \tag{2}$$

Note that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent.

From $(1)$, it follows from usual calculus that the ML estimate of $\lambda$ is

$$\hat\lambda(\boldsymbol x)=\frac{4}{\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i+15}$$

Comment: I have not learnt about censoring as of yet, so thank you for filling in this information for me! I'll read this asap - also, this is exactly what I needed. I cannot believe that I missed it, I was pretty close to seeing this outcome however I was not sure whether I could take the pdf distribution as you did. You have my sincerest regards

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with your second interpretation as I haven't been taught sufficiently with indicator functions under these occasions.